# Gradlew dependeny resolution stuck for ever

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle, gradlew

I tried to search this error clue, the closest i get this gradle forum where they discuss about enforcePlatform to be possible solution but we are no using any "platform" in our build gradle scripts.
And every time i run any gradlew command i get this message and build takes for hours which normally it completes in few minutes.

Any leads or clue are much appreciated. Thank you!!

this the gradlew version

---

### Gradle 6.8.3

Build time:   2021-02-22 16:13:28 UTC
Revision:     9e26b4a9ebb910eaa1b8da8ff8575e514bc61c78

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.19 (Eclipse Adoptium 11.0.19+7)
OS:           Mac OS X 14.0 aarch64

```
The dependency resolution engine wasn't able to find a version of module org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient which satisfied all requirements because the graph wasn't stable enough. The highest version was selected in order to stabilize selection.
Features available in a stable graph like version alignment are not guaranteed in this case.
The dependency resolution engine wasn't able to find a version of module org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio which satisfied all requirements because the graph wasn't stable enough. The highest version was selected in order to stabilize selection.
Features available in a stable graph like version alignment are not guaranteed in this case.
```

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-you-resolve-dependency-resolution-engine-wasnt-able-to-find-a-version-warning/43872
checked above forum not helpful.